# Get data from API and display on tempate

Tags: python, django, api

I am trying to get data from the stackoverflow API and display them on an html table in my template.

So far I have managed to get the data but cannot display them in the template. I end up getting the last one. I do know my loop is wrong, have tried a bunch of stuff but can't seem to figure it out.

My code so far:

```
def get_questions(request):
    context = {}
    r = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate=1525737600&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow').json()
    for item in r['items']:
        context['owner'] = item['owner']['display_name']
        context['title'] = item['title']
        #some other attrs here

    template = 'questions/questions_list.html'
    context['greeting'] = 'Hello'

    return render(request,template,context)
```

My template code:
I haven't done anything fancy yet. Pretty simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ owner }} - {{ title }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you also post the template code. Thanks.

Comment: Also in each iteration of the loop you're updating the same keys, so they would have the value only of the last iteration

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues yeah I kinda got that. Any help please?

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib have added the template code. Nothing fancy so far as you can see.

Comment: when you say `last one wrong`, what do you mean?

Comment: So what seems to be the problem? You have only the last value in your context, and that's what gets displayed right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to append your result to a list and the render that list in your template.

**Demo:**
*views.py*

```
def get_questions(request):
    context = {}
    r = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate=1525737600&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow').json()
    dataList = []
    for item in r['items']:
        dataList.append({'owner': item['owner']['display_name'], 'title': item['title']})
        #some other attrs here

    template = 'questions/questions_list.html'
    context['greeting'] = 'Hello'
    context['data'] = dataList

    return render(request,template,context)
```

**Template**
*Iterate over your result and get all data*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for i in data %}
        {{ i.owner }} - {{ i.title }}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```